# Laravel select data after Join 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello, i have problem with selecting data from 3 tables that has relationship to each other in Laravel 5.2. First, i have 3 tables:

1. games('id','name','price','image')
2. transactions('id','user_id','game_id','date')
3. rates('id','user_id','game_id','rating')

I want to select the games that users have bought (in Transaction) and also the detail of the games and the average rating of each games.

This is my code :

```
public function indexMyGames()
    {
        $trans = DB::table('transactions')
            ->join('games', 'games.id', '=', 'transactions.game_id')
            ->join('rates','rates.game_id','=','games.id')
            ->select('transactions.*','games.name','games.image',DB::raw('AVG(rates.rating) as average_rate'))
            ->groupBy('games.id')
            ->where('transactions.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();

        return view('games.mygames',['trans' => $trans]);
    }
```

and i called the function:

```
@foreach($trans as $tran)
                    <div style="margin: 10px;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;width: 23%;border: 1px solid lightgrey;float: left;">
                        <div>
                            <img src="{{ asset('/games/' . $tran->image) }}" width="250px" height="350px">
                        </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
                        <p><label>{{$tran->name}}</label></p>
                        <p>Rating : {{round($tran->average_rate)}}/5</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

The result is only 1 data only, it gives me only 1 game while the result should be 3 game.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: How many rows you are getting without group by ?

Comment: Share data set of above tables ?

Comment: You are querying the game that the current login user bought, and the average rating of the current login user given. Are these what you want to query?